# tensorflow: how to reload from a saved checkpoint and do incremental change

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have checkpoint from a pre-trained model A but not its graph-building code. Now I want to reload model A and add sub-graph B to it to get final model C. It's like that **C = A + B**.  However, since model A is very well trained I don't want to train it in C. **I only want to train sub-graph B in C**. In other words, sub-graph A only participate in prediction phase(forward propagation) but not training phase(backward propagation), and sub-graph B participate both phase and is what I want to train. **The aim is that with the help of sub-graph B, now model C will outperform model A**.

How can this be achieved? I guess this may be related to saver/restore but I don't know how to get all things work together. Any code snippet will be greatly appreciated.

I'm using tensorflow 1.12

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you want to do is quite a typical machine learning use case, and it can be achieved in a few manners.

If you just have a saved checkpoint but not source code of the pre-trained model, after loading the model from checkpoint, you need to :

- Clear `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` collection to make variables
  from ckpt non-trainable by the fine tuning model
- Clear `tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES` collection to make variables
  from ckpt not re-initialized by the fine tuning model

And then build and train the fine tuning model, as usual.

The code below is tested with TensorFlow 1.12

```py
import os
import shutil
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from absl import logging, app, flags


flags.DEFINE_string('pre_train_model_checkpoint_path', '/tmp/pre_train_model', '')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


def train_and_save_pre_train_model():
    # model: y = w*x + b
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None), name='x')
    y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None), name='y')
    w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=())
    b = tf.get_variable('b', shape=())
    y = w*x + b
    y_pred = tf.identity(y, 'y_pred')
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(2000):
        x_val = np.random.rand(128)
        y_val = x_val * 2.0 - 1.0 # to make w=2.0 and b=-1.0
        sess.run(train_op, {x: x_val, y_true: y_val})
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    shutil.rmtree(FLAGS.pre_train_model_checkpoint_path)
    os.makedirs(FLAGS.pre_train_model_checkpoint_path)
    save_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.pre_train_model_checkpoint_path, 'ckpt')
    saver.save(sess, save_path, global_step=100)
    return sess.run((w, b));


def main(_):
    w_val, b_val = train_and_save_pre_train_model()
    # to check if pre train model is trained as expected
    logging.info('w_val={}, b_val={}'.format(w_val, b_val))

    # load pre train model
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    meta_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.pre_train_model_checkpoint_path, 'ckpt-100.meta') 
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_file)
    save_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.pre_train_model_checkpoint_path, 'ckpt-100')
    sess = tf.Session()
    saver.restore(sess, save_path)
    x = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('x:0')
    y_pred = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('y_pred:0')
    w = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('w:0')
    b = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('b:0')

    # to make variable from ckpt non-trainable by fine tuning model
    tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES).clear()
    # to make variable from ckpt not re-initialized by fine tuning model
    tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES).clear()

    # build fine-tuning model: y2 = w2*y + b2
    w2 = tf.get_variable('w2', shape=())
    b2 = tf.get_variable('b2', shape=())
    y2_pred = w2*y_pred + b2
    y2_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None), name='y2')
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y2_true, y2_pred)
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(2000):
        x_val = np.random.rand(128)
        y2_val = (x_val * w_val + b_val) * 10.0 + 1.0 # to make w2=10.0 and b2=1.0
        sess.run(train_op, {x: x_val, y2_true: y2_val})
    w2_val, b2_val = sess.run((w2, b2)) 
    logging.info('w2_val={}, b2_val={}'.format(w2_val, b2_val))

    # assert w and b is not trained
    w_val_after_fine_tuning, b_val_after_fine_tuning = sess.run((w, b))
    logging.info('w_val_after_fine_tuning={}, b_val_after_fine_tuning={}'.format(w_val_after_fine_tuning, b_val_after_fine_tuning))
    assert(w_val == w_val_after_fine_tuning)
    assert(b_val == b_val_after_fine_tuning)
    logging.info('all good')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(main)
```